# DecryptByPassPhrase returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt the pass of the user in my table User, column password varchar(20)

So, Im using this to encrypt:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ENCRYPTARPASSB](
@CLAVE VARCHAR(20),
@PASS VARCHAR(20) OUT 
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
@PASS = CONVERT(varchar(20), ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('enelhogar',@CLAVE),2)
END
```

This works fine and returns something like this '01000000B4B51D0B8356'.

But my problem is when I try to decrypt the pass. Im using this but doesnt works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_DESENCRIPTARPASSB](
@CLAVE VARCHAR(20),
@PASS VARCHAR(20) OUT 
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
@PASS = convert(varchar(20),DecryptByPassPhrase('enelhogar',CONVERT(varchar(20),@clave,2)))
END
```

But always return null. I was reading about the topic but I cant find the solution.

Any idea?? THanks in advance!

Comment: check the len of `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('enelhogar',@CLAVE)` is it less than 20 ?

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @Squirrel no, it's exactly 20

Comment: @zaphdo you have any example?

Comment: try `SELECT LEN(CONVERT(varchar(max), ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('enelhogar', @CLAVE), 2))`

Comment: can you explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecryptByPassPhrase` gets a `varbinary` variable and returns `nvarchar`.
So you should do as below:

```
DECLARE @BinaryCLAVE  varbinary(1000);
SET @BinaryCLAVE =  CONVERT( varbinary(1000) , @CLAVE,1)
SELECT @PASS = DecryptByPassPhrase('enelhogar', @BinaryCLAVE ))
```